# Is there a way to fetch latest email from "Mail reader sampler" or "Beanshell Sampler"

Tags: email, jmeter

I am able to fetch email from my email account using POP3 via "Mail Reader Sampler" listener. But its not retrieving latest email.
Is it possible to extract the latest email using Beanshell Sampler. If yes, can you please share the code if this is achievable.

As per below discussion - looks like it is not doable. But, wanted to check if this is achievable using any means?
[Stackoverflow Discussion on how to fetch required email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39230364/jmeter-mail-reader-sampler-controlling-which-msgs-to-fetch)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing advanced scenarios using JMeter Mail Reader sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075766/testing-advanced-scenarios-using-jmeter-mail-reader-sampler)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically, check out the following methods:

- [Folder.getMessageCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#getMessageCount--) - *Get total number of messages in this Folder*
- [Folder.getMessage(int msgnum)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#getMessage-int-) - *Get the Message object corresponding to the given message number*

According to the JavaDoc

> Messages are numbered starting at 1 through the total number of message in the folder.

So the number of the last message will always be the same as the total number of messages in the given folder.

Example code which reads last email using POP3 protocol

```
import javax.mail.Folder
import javax.mail.Message
import javax.mail.Session
import javax.mail.Store

String host = "host"
String user = "username"
String password = "password"

Properties properties = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties)
Store store = session.getStore("pop3")
store.connect(host, user, password)
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox")
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)

int msgCount = inbox.getMessageCount()
Message last = inbox.getMessage(msgCount)

//do what you need with the "last" message
inbox.close(true)
store.close()
```

I would also recommend forgetting about Beanshell, whenever you need to perform scripting - use [JSR223 Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as Groovy has much better performance, it is more Java-compliant and it has some nice language features. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) guide for more details.